# React Component's onClick handler not binding to "this"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component in which I am trying to pass a span tag an onClick event handler. The event handler is called "askQuestion". I bind the onClick event handler to the context of the component with the .bind(this, parameter) function.

Despite my attempt to bind to "this" I'm still getting an error in the dev tools console saying "cannot read property askQuestion of undefined." I'm pretty sure this error means that askQuestion is not bound properly to the context of the component. I need help binding askQuestion properly.

Here is the component:

```
class Questions extends Component {
  askQuestion(question) {
    alert("hello");
  }

  addQuestion(question, index) {
    return (
      <div key={index} className="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <span onClick={this.askQuestion.bind(this, question)}>
          {question.q}
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="questions" className="row">
        <h2>Questions</h2>
        {this.props.questions.map(this.addQuestion)}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

}

Comment: So I got this working by binding this.addQuestion to "this" like such:

this.props.questions.map(this.addQuestion.bind(this)}

Anyone understand why that works properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation**

The problem is that you use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which does not bind `this` unless explicitly told to, and the context of the callback is, in turn, undefined. From the documentation:

> If a `thisArg` parameter is provided to `map`, it will be passed to callback when invoked, for use as its this value. **Otherwise, the value undefined will be passed for use as its `this` value**. (emphasis mine)

Where `thisArg` is an optional argument of `map`, see [`Array.prototype.map` Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#syntax). That means, when you do:

```
{this.props.questions.map(this.addQuestion)}
```

`this` context is undefined when calling `this.addQuestion`, thus it is undefined in the call to `addQuestion`. Let me illustrate the problem further by taking a look at your `addQuestion` method:

```
addQuestion(question, index) {
  return (
    <div key={index} className="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <span onClick={this.askQuestion.bind(this, question)}>
        {question.q}
      </span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here, since, as mentioned earlier, `this` is undefined, you are actually trying to do:

```
undefined.addQuestion.bind(undefined, question)
```

which throws the error because `undefined` has no function `addQuestion`.

---

**Solution**

Again, from the documentation:

> **Syntax**
>
> `var new_array = arr.map(callback[, thisArg])`
>
> **`thisArg`**
>
> Optional. Value to use as this when executing callback.

You can see that we can explicitly pass a `this` context to `map`, to be used as `this` context in the callback. That means we can pass an additional argument to be `this` in the function. This can be applied like so:

```
{this.props.questions.map(this.addQuestion, this)}
```

Since `this` refers to the actual component here, the component is passed as `this`. That will then correctly call the method `addQuestion` from the component. An alternative and functionally equivalent way to do is like so:

```
{this.props.questions.map(this.addQuestion.bind(this))}
```

Again, since `this` refers to the actual component here, the component is bound as the `this` context of the method. That means, in the call to `addQuestion`, the component is `this`, like the above solution.

---

Another thing I'd recommend is that, instead of creating a new function every time with `bind`, do it once in the constructor:

```
constructor(/* props if needed */) {
    /* super(props) if needed */
    this.addQuestion = this.addQuestion.bind(this);
}
```

That way, the bound method is already `this.addQuestion`. You can then get rid of all your `bind(this)`s, but keep your `bind(this, question)`, as you bind with an argument.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the proper way to do this in React is to bind this in the constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.askQuestion = this.askQuestion.bind(this)
}
```